# Find and raise a window in KDE4 with shortcut

Tags: kde, xorg, kde-4, window-manager

I was wondering about a possibility to find and raise some window in KDE4 with shortcut. Currently in KDE 4.4 there is a possibility to switch to window from krunner (Alt-F2). Say, I have an open konsole widow somewhere and to switch to it, I can Alt-F2, write konsole and choose konsole window I need from the list. This is great, but too much typing. I would like to have a keyboard shortcut to do the same.

Maybe some DBUS magic can do that? Any ideas?

Thaks!
Andre

Answer (score 4):

you can use [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) as the basis:

```
 % wmctrl -a WIN
```

the only thing you have to do is find out "WIN", which is the id for the window matching a certain criteria.

```
<WIN>  This argument specifies the window. By default it's
       interpreted as a string. The string is matched
       against the window titles and the first matching
       window is used. The matching isn't case sensitive
       and the string may appear in any position
       of the title.
```

Comment: I was thinking about more of kde-way for solving this. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @well, you have to tell X to pick window Y based on a certain pattern anyway ...

Comment: This works well with xbindkeys.  I went this route after KDE started forgetting my windows shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Left click on the the window title bar, scroll to advanced and then click on the window shortcut configuration.  I can't find out how to get rid of them.