# How to make persistent shortcuts to windows in KDE4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window, kde-4, persistence

This answer [Find and raise a window in KDE4 with shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/147594/find-and-raise-a-window-in-kde4-with-shortcut/148684#148684) tells how to set a keyboard shortcut which activates a particular windows. It works wonderfully. But if I close the application and restart it, the shortcut resets. Is there a way to make it persistent?

Comment: You said you needed this for *Konsole*. Maybe try *Yakuake* instead?

Comment: I didn't mention konsole. My motivation example was gkrellm which always hides behind other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the following KDE menu

- `System Settings`
- `Shortcuts and Gestures`
- `Custom Shortcuts`

Now select

- `Edit`
- `New`
- `Global Shortcut`
- `Command/URL`

Which allows you to set a trigger and the action `wmctrl -a "<application>"`.

In KDE 5, you need to enable the new action by clicking the checkbox next to it in the tree (or its group, if its group is not enabled).

Notes:

- Tested with KDE 4.11.5 and KDE Frameworks 5.18.0.
- Verify that `wmctrl` is installed.
- The global shortcut will not appear in the title bar of the window.
- If you select the `Examples` group, there is an entry `Activate KSIRC Window` but I could not find a way to recreate similar entries using the user interface. It is possible to export the example group to a `*.khotkeys` file, manually create such entries and import them but using `wmcrtl` seems more comfortable.